# Populating consecutive Textboxes and Labels w.r.t the Index of the value in a collection

Tags: c#, winforms

I have, in a form, consecutive textboxes and labels named tb1,tb2,tb3... and label1,label2,label3....

I have a dictionary holding number of Key value pairs.

How to populate the labels and textboxes corresponding to the value pairs in the dictionary?
Eg: dic.Key[1] -> label1 and dic.value[1] to tb1... like that.

I don't get any idea to try this.

Comment: I think you should define textboxes and labels as an array. And that would become possible.

Comment: Why not just use a `GridView`?

Comment: @sergio: Should only use these controls pal...

Answer (score 2):

In the other answer it is suggested to create a collection of labels and textboxes. My concern with that approach is that a developer may forget to do that or the order may get changed.

Every control has the `Name` property which stores that control's name. This property is set by Visual Studio. In your code, if you are not playing (read changing) with the Name property of controls, you can use the below code to achieve what you wanted to.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dic.Count; i++)
{
    // As Control.Find returns an array of controls whose name match the specified string,
    // in this example I had picked the first control
    // you can make it more robust by checking
    // - the number of controls returned,
    // - the type of control, etc
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) this.Controls.Find("tb" + (i + 1).ToString(), true)[0];
    Label lbl = (Label) this.Controls.Find("label" + (i + 1).ToString(), true)[0];


    txt.Text = dic[i].Value;
    lbl.Text = dic[i].Key;
}
```

Comment: That was my other idea... Yet I don't like the idea of working with parameters you don't set yourself. I know that VS will probably not change the Name tomorrow, but that's just my liking. Plus it's not as clean as the array approach. Valid answer anyway... FOR NOW O.O

Comment: @Kilazur: Even i don't like the idea to work with something that I'm not sure of, but when it comes to believe on a person vs an application, I trust the application more :P

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would simply be to initialize a List (or two) in your form's constructor, putting all your labels and text boxes inside, so you can check them while looping through your dictionary.

```
private List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
private List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

public MyForm()
{
    labels.Add(myLabel1);
    labels.Add(myLabel2);
    labels.Add(myLabel3);
    textBoxes.Add(myTB1);
    textBoxes.Add(myTB2);
    textBoxes.Add(myTB3);
}

private void addValuesFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dic.Count; i++)
    {
        labels[i].Text = dic[i].Key;
        textBoxes[i].Text = dic[i].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll tell me if it doesn't, my mouse is already over the edit button :p